# How weird does this phrase sound to your native speaker ears?

Tags: grammatical-number

I was watching the Eat Sleep Dream English You Tube channel and I noticed this: "The city's immigrants groups". I can think of lots of situations where the qualifying noun it's not in the plural form. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be correct, if it was referring to groups which represent the immigrants, like you might say "[special interests groups](http://www.essa.eu.org/special-interests-groups/)", though even in that example you can see that they mix and match it with uses of "special interest groups".

I'd personally say that "the city's immigrant groups" might be more correct if they wanted to refer to the whole of a community rather than a group of people working in support of those communities (which makes more sense when talking about the influence of immigrants on regional accents).